# Entity Framework Core Functions Missing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to move to Entity Framework Core from Entity Framework, and I've created a sample DataContext project as follows:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
}
```

This code is loosely based on the Microsoft tutorials here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

However, I seem to be missing all the usual Entity Framework functions, such as Where(), Singe(), FirstOrDefault() etc.

All I have is Add(), Attach(), Find(), as well as the range and async versions of these.

How do I get the rest of the functions?

I've added ENtityFrameworkCore & EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, versions 1.1.2

Comment: try using System.Linq;

Comment: @Alexandru-DanPop Damn... that was easy!